# C++ container to support row and column lookup

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, containers, comparison, lookup

Given several data types, I'm trying to implement a method to determine which type can be converted to by all other types.

Int -> Float -> Boolean

A int can be converted to a float which can converted to a boolean. However this is not the case for the other way round, e.g. a boolean cannot be converted to a float.

So given that I have the following types: int, float, boolean, the type that can be converted to by all other types is a boolean. This can be figured out using the following table where all the types in the problem are compared against one another to determine if they can be converted to it:

|  | int | float | boolean |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| int | true | true | true |
| float | false | true | true |
| boolean | false | false | true |

e.g. in the int row, a int can be converted to a int, float and boolean. However in the float row, a float cannot be converted to a int, but can be converted to a float or boolean.

The boolean column is all true, showing that all other types can be converted to it.

I'm trying to implement this logic into C++ however I'm having trouble determining the best kind of container for the table in terms of performance. I already have a method called `canConvert(Type1, Type2)` which returns true/false if `Type1` can be converted to `Type2`, which will be used to populate the table. The table will require lookups via both row and column, and also require a scan at the end column by column to determine if all of the column's rows are true.

What would be the best kind of container to support such this kind of comparison?

Comment: Opinion-based, definitely. You can start with `std::vector<std::vector<bool>>` if Type1 and Type2 can convert to int. Or `std::map<std::pair<Type, Type>, bool>`.

Comment: If you have fixed number of types, then you can use simple `std::vector<bool>` with size of `numTypes*numTypes`. And access it as 2-dimensional array. This is fast and efficient space-wise.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with the title or the flags. Please change both to properly express, what your are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [`std::is_convertible`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_convertible), but I think your table doesnt match the definition of `std::is_convertible` (eg `std::is_convertible<int,float>::value` and `std::is_convertible<float,int>::value` are both `true`).

Nevertheless, your table only depends on types, hence there is no need to make the table occupy memory. You can encode the information in types:

```
 template <typename T,typename U>
 struct my_table : std::false_type {};
```

I chose to make `false` the default, so that you only need to specialize for the `true` cases:

```
 template <> struct my_table<bool,int> : std::true_type {};
 template <> struct my_table<bool,float> : std::true_type {};
 template <> struct my_table<bool,bool> : std::true_type {};
 // ...
```